# Register object for Trigger Factory

Tags: apex, trigger

In my org there is already a trigger factory setup. In OpportunityLineItem the trigger had logic that by my research and other examples should have been in the handler.

```
trigger SL_OpportunityProductTrigger on OpportunityLineItem (
 before insert, 
 before update, 
 before delete, 
 after insert, 
 after update, 
 after delete, 
 after undelete) {
  SL_OpportunityProductHandler handler = new SL_OpportunityProductHandler();
   if (Trigger.isBefore) {
     //call your handler.before method
     if(trigger.isInsert)
     {
      handler.onBeforeInsert(Trigger.new);
     }
 } else if (Trigger.isAfter) {     
 }
}
```

So I rewrote the trigger to be this:

```
trigger SL_OpportunityProductTrigger on OpportunityLineItem (before insert, before update, before delete, after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
SL_TriggerFactory.createTriggerHandler(OpportunityLineItem.sObjectType);
```

}

Then I rewrote the handler class to be this:

```
 global class SL_OpportunityProductHandler extends SL_TriggerHandlerBase {

public static boolean isAfterInsert = true; //created boolean for avoid recursive call 
public static boolean isBeforeUpdate = true;
public static boolean isBeforeInsert = true;
public static boolean isAfterUpdate = true;

public override void beforeInsert(List<SObject> newListGeneric){
    List<OpportunityLineItem> newList = (List<OpportunityLineItem>) newListGeneric;
    /* BEFORE INSERT METHODS START */
    if(SL_OpportunityProductHandler.isBeforeInsert) {
        populateSolutionsConsultant(newList);  
        SL_OpportunityProductHandler.isBeforeInsert = false;
    }
    /* BEFORE INSERT METHODS END */
}

public override void beforeUpdate(Map<Id, SObject> oldMapGeneric, Map<Id, SObject> newMapGeneric){
    Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> oldMap = (Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>) oldMapGeneric;
    Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> newMap = (Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>) newMapGeneric;
    /* BEFORE UPDATE METHODS START */

    /* BEFORE UPDATE METHODS END */
}

public override void beforeDelete(Map<Id, SObject> oldMapGeneric){
    Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> oldMap = (Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>) oldMapGeneric;
    /* BEFORE DELETE METHODS START */

    /* BEFORE DELETE METHODS END */
}

public override void afterInsert(Map<Id, SObject> newMapGeneric){
    Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> newMap = (Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>) newMapGeneric;
    /* AFTER INSERT METHODS START */

    /* AFTER INSERT METHODS END */
}    

public override void afterUpdate(Map<Id, SObject> oldMapGeneric, Map<Id, SObject> newMapGeneric){
    Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> oldMap = (Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>) oldMapGeneric;
    Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> newMap = (Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>) newMapGeneric;
    /* AFTER UPDATE METHODS START */

    /* AFTER UPDATE METHODS END */
}

public override void afterDelete(Map<Id, SObject> oldMapGeneric){
    Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> oldMap = (Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>) oldMapGeneric;
    /* AFTER DELETE METHODS START */

    /* AFTER DELETE METHODS END */
}

public override void afterUndelete(Map<Id, SObject> newMapGeneric){
    Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> newMap = (Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>) newMapGeneric;
    /* AFTER UNDELETE METHODS START */

    /* AFTER UNDELETE METHODS END */
}
```

Then I have methods for the actions that I want to take. The problem is I keep getting an error: "No Trigger handler registered for Object Type: OpportunityLineItem"
It's the same error that's described to do in the [cookbook](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/trigger-pattern-for-tidy-streamlined-bulkified-triggers)

The trigger factory class is:

```
public with sharing class SL_TriggerFactory
{

public static Boolean FakeException = false;
public static Boolean KillSwitchEnabled = SL_AppConfigSupport.KillSwitchEnabled;
public static String KillList = SL_AppConfigSupport.KillList;

/** 
* @date 11/9/2014
* @description Creates the appropriate handler and dispatches the trigger event to the handler's event handler method.
* @param Schema.sObjectType Object type to process (SObject.sObjectType)
*/
public static void createTriggerHandler(Schema.sObjectType soType){
    String soTypeName = soType.getDescribe().getName();
    Set<String> deactivatedObjects = new Set<String>();
    if (KillList != null && KillList != ''){
        deactivatedObjects = new Set<String>(KillList.split('\n'));
    }
    Set<String> deactivatedObjectsNoWhitespace = new Set<String>();
    for (String s: deactivatedObjects){
        deactivatedObjectsNoWhitespace.add(s.deleteWhitespace());
    }

    if (!(KillSwitchEnabled || (KillList != null ? deactivatedObjectsNoWhitespace.contains(soTypeName) : false))){
        // Initial Push to Diagnostic Log
        String beforeOrAfter = 'before';
        if (Trigger.isAfter)
            beforeOrAfter = 'after';
        String dmlState = 'Insert';
        if (Trigger.isUpdate){
            dmlState = 'Update';
        }
        else if (Trigger.isDelete){
            dmlState = 'Delete';
        }
        else if (Trigger.isUndelete){
            dmlState = 'Undelete';
        }
        SL_DiagnosticsInstrumentation.Push(beforeOrAfter + dmlState + ' Trigger for ' + soTypeName + ' Object');
        try{
            SL_ITriggerHandler handler = getTriggerHandler(soType);
            if (handler == null || FakeException)
                throw new SL_FrameworkException('No Trigger handler registered for Object Type: ' + soType);
            execute(handler, soTypeName, beforeOrAfter+dmlState);
            // Final Pop from Diagnostic Log
            SL_DiagnosticsInstrumentation.Pop();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            SL_DiagnosticsInstrumentation.DebugException(ex);
            SL_DiagnosticsInstrumentation.PopAll();
            if (!SL_AppConfigSupport.DiagnosticsEnabled && SL_AppConfigSupport.ThrowExceptions){
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
* @date 11/9/2014
* @description Gets the appropriate handler based on the SObject. It constructs the instance of the handler
*               dynamically using the Type API. The name of the handler has to follow this format:
*               <ObjectName>Triggerhandler. For e.g. for the Account object, the handler has to be named
*               as AccountTriggerhandler. For the custom object Custom__c, the name should be CustomTriggerhandler.
* @param Schema.sObjectType Object type to create the handler
* @return SL_ITriggerhandler A trigger handler if one exists, otherwise null.
*/
private static SL_ITriggerHandler getTriggerHandler(Schema.sObjectType soType){
    String originalTypeName = soType.getDescribe().getName();
    String handlerTypeName = null;
    String handlerName;
    if (originalTypeName.toLowerCase().endsWith('__c')) {
        Integer index = originalTypeName.toLowerCase().indexOf('__c');
        handlerName = originalTypeName.substring(0, index);
    }
    else {
        handlerName = originalTypeName;
    }
    if (handlerName.length() > 23){
        handlerName = handlerName.substring(0,23);
    }
    handlerTypeName = 'SL_' + handlerName + 'TriggerHandler';    

    Type obType = Type.forName(handlerTypeName);
    SL_ITriggerHandler handler = (obType == null) ? null : (SL_ITriggerHandler)obType.newInstance();
    return handler;
}
}
```

Is there something that I have to write in the handler so that the factory knows that I have a handler for this object? In the criteria it says if the handler is null then give an error how can I ensure there is a handler?

Does this make sense?

Comment: Why are you using the `global` modifier? You should only use that when you *know* you need it. Basically, never.

Comment: I copied a lot of it from Opportunity trigger/handler that we already had. Think change to public?

Comment: Yes, change to `public`. Never use `global` unless you are developing a managed package and can rigorously justify why you are doing so.

Comment: I added the trigger factory class code, forgot it at first.

Comment: Do you have the relevant logic I mentioned in your `getHandler` method?

Comment: I added, I think I see the problem in that it's looking for a handler class to have "TriggerHandler" in the name. My assumption is because the original handler didn't reference the trigger factory like the other handlers we have like Opportunity or Account the handler name was not setup in the correct convention and thus we get the error because the code could not find the expected name...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44004/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-dan-wooding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `TriggerFactory.getHandler` method uses an `if` chain. Not an ideal architecture IMO but the way to fix it would seem to be to add a clause to that method for your object in particular.

```
if (soType == OpportunityLineItem.sObjectType) {
    return new SL_OpportunityProductHandler();
}
```

Now that you've added your `getHandler` implementation, make sure that you are getting the correct value for `handlerTypeName`. If you want to hew to a rigorous naming convention, you should rename your handler `SL_OpportunityLineItemTriggerHander`, because the `API Name` of this object is `OpportunityLineItem`, not `OpportunityProduct`.